# Remove the cart subtotal in Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I am working on the cart page for my site and I have a question. I want to try and hide the subtotal after each product price BUT still keep the total cart subtotal. I added a screenshot as a reference below. Any help would be fantastic!

[annotated screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YmYx.png)

Comment: The only option I can think of now is to override the template (cart.php) from theme/child theme and remove the lines 33 (subtotal label) and 125-129 ( subtotal values )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be accomplished by CSS.

eg.

```
.woocommerce table.cart td:nth-of-type(6), .woocommerce table.cart th:nth-of-type(6) {
display: none;
}
```

As explained here: https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-hide-column-cart-table/

Comment: Worked great! Thank you

Comment: Glad to hear :)

Comment: Thanks again! Have a great day!